# CSS border not working in IE6

Tags: html, css

I have a css class (given below). The border element is working fine in firefox, it creates a 6px white border around the image. But in IE(6) it is not creating any border ie only displays the image. Pls help me out I need to figure it out quickly.

```
.pimage2 {
    background:url(../images/img2.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 469px;
    height:203px;   
    border:7px solid #ffffff;   

}
```

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: Can you post the HTML code also?

Comment: Here it is...

<td   class="pimage2"></td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you're using the CSS on a table cell like this:

```
<td class="pimage2"></td>
```

But IE6 won't see this and you won't be able to get the border to show.

To get the border around it, just add a non-breaking space entity in the table cell. Like so:

```
<td class="pimage2">&‎nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe with black color: ?

```
border:7px solid #000;
```

Comment: Are you assuming the OP put a white border on  white background?

Comment: Even black color frame is not appearing in IE, though its appearing in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

To get the border in the latest css version, you have to write border-style first then the rest of the attributes or design of the border is considered.

```css
border:blueviolet;
border-width: 0.5px;
border-style:solid;
```

Or, the border will not render.